# handler not working (html, javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

```
<form method="post" action=".">
   <label class="input-label">First Name </label><input field="first_name" class="input-edit" maxlength="30" type="text" value="{{ user.first_name }}" />               

  <label class="input-label"> Email </label><input field="email" class="input-edit" maxlength="75" type="text" value="{{ user.email }}" onkeyup="checkMail(this)" />

  <input type="submit" id="save-changes-settings-submit" class="save-changes-button" uid="{{ user.id }}" value="Save changes" />
</form>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        function isValidEmailAddress(emailAddress) {
            var pattern = new RegExp(/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i);
            return pattern.test(emailAddress);
        };

        function checkMail(input){
            if( !isValidEmailAddress( input ) ){
                alert("wrff");
                $(this).addClass("correct-input");
            }
            else{
                alert("correct");
                $(this).addClass("wrong-input");
            }
        };
    });   
</script>
```

This is my html and java script code. But when I run this in browser it doesn't work. Firefox gives the error that 'checkMail' function is not defined. But, as one can see, it is there. I tried putting the script on top, it still isn't working. I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: btw, its "Javascript", not "Java Script". Javascript doesnt really have anything to do with Java.

Comment: I wrote javascript only and I know that. But, it wasn't in the dictionary. So, it was showing error. I was in a hurry, so corrected it according to the dictionary. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

checkMail exists outside of the global context.  Only code that exists within this function

```
function(){
    function isValidEmailAddress(emailAddress) {
        var pattern = new RegExp(/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i);
        return pattern.test(emailAddress);
    };

    function checkMail(input){
        if( !isValidEmailAddress( input ) ){
            alert("wrff");
            $(this).addClass("correct-input");
        }
        else{
            alert("correct");
            $(this).addClass("wrong-input");
        }
    };
}
```

can access the function checkMail.  Probably the best way to do this would be to use jQuery's keyup() method to register an event handler.

```
$("#inputElement").keyup(function(){ // your code here... });
```

Make sure this goes inside your $(document).ready() function.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to wrap functions in `$(document).ready() { ... }`, functions aren't triggered `onload` since they are called, the DOM will already be loaded. And since `$(this)` references a jQuery element, when you call it, there is no `this` to reference.

Answer (score 0):

#### Put your functions out of document.ready and change you input onkeyup to onblur event and pass argument this.value

onblur="checkMail(this.value)"